# Get percentage of occurrence of each value for certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with many questions, each in a separate column. The rows are answers to those questions, which are on a scale of 1-5.:

```
q1  q2  q3  q4  q5
4   5   2   5   2
4   5   5   5   5
1   4   5   4   5
3   1   4   1   4
4   3   2   3   2
2   4   3   4   3
```

I would like to see, for each question, what percentage did each value get:

```
    1          2       3       4       5
q1  0.17    0.17    0.17    0.50    0.00
q2  0.17    0.00    0.17    0.33    0.33
q3  0.00    0.33    0.17    0.17    0.33
q4  0.17    0.00    0.17    0.33    0.33
q5  0.00    0.33    0.17    0.17    0.33
```

How do I do this? I've been trying with groupby and value counts, but no luck, e.g.:

```
df.value_counts(subset=['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5']).reset_index()

df.groupby(['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5'].size().unstack().apply(lambda x:x*100/x.sum()).T.reset_index()
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.value_counts(normalize=True)).T.fillna(0).round(2)
```

output:

```
       1     2     3     4     5
q1  0.17  0.17  0.17  0.50  0.00
q2  0.17  0.00  0.17  0.33  0.33
q3  0.00  0.33  0.17  0.17  0.33
q4  0.17  0.00  0.17  0.33  0.33
q5  0.00  0.33  0.17  0.17  0.33
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I have another column for Country, and I would like to see the split by country?

Comment: Then you would need to use something like `df.drop(columns='Country').apply(lambda s: s.groupby(df['Country']).value_counts(normalize=True)).T.fillna(0).round(2)`